# MVC Core - Passing ID to view and pre-selecting value in selectlist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

First of all forgive me as I am new to MVC.

I have a view which shows server(s) related to a particular application. If none exist, or the user wants to add an additional application/server relationship, they click on "Create New". From this link, I would like the ApplicationID to be passed to the Create view, and the selectlist for Applications to default to the correct Application. Or alternatively, display the application name/id in a label. I would also like to pass the ApplicationId back when "Back to List" is selected.

Model:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ApplicationPortfolio.Models
{
    [Table("tblServerApp")]
    public class ServerApp
    {
        public int ServerAppId { get; set; }
        public int? ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public int? ServerId { get; set; }

        public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
        public virtual Server Server { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```cs
// GET: ServerApps/Create
public IActionResult Create(int? id)
{
    ViewData["ApplicationId"] = new SelectList(_context.Application, "ApplicationID", "Name", id);
    ViewData["ServerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Server, "ServerId", "ServerName");
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model ApplicationPortfolio.Models.ServerApp

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>ServerApp</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Create">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ApplicationId" class="control-label"></label>
                        <select asp-for="ApplicationId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ApplicationId"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ServerId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="ServerId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ServerId"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is it you are asking? What is the problem?

Comment: Hi @VictoriaM，any update about this case?

Answer (score 1):

After my test,I found your problem may in your code:

```
 ViewData["ApplicationId"] = new SelectList(_context.Application, "ApplicationID", "Name", id);
```

`ApplicationID` and `Name` should be same with the name in your `Application` model.

If your model is(`example`) :

```
public class Application
    {
        [Key]
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public List<ServerApp> ServerApps { get; set; }
    }
```

Your code should be(`Please pay attention to whether the case and match`) :

```
ViewData["ApplicationId"] = new SelectList(_context.Applications, "ApplicationId", "ApplicationName",id);
```

And if you want to pass the `ApplicationId` back to `Index`,you can try following code.

```
@model ServerApp
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}    
<h4>ServerApp</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ApplicationId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select id="select" asp-for="ApplicationId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ApplicationId"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ServerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select  asp-for="ServerId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ServerId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-info">Back to List</button>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
<script>
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var e = document.getElementById("select");
        var strUser = e.value;
        window.location.href = "/home/index?id=" + strUser; 
    })
</script>
}
```

**Test Result:**
[image]

Comment: Hi @VictoriaM，if my answer is helpful,can you [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?Thank you very much!